# How to configure DEV part in Spring Application?

Tags: java, spring

I started Spring Project. I have added some dependencies.

Previously, I were commenting some dependencies as Security, Mysql driver, if it is not needed for me.

But how to disable them without commenting dependencies?

Maybe some properties are needed for that?

For example, I want to use H2Database to test  project, but PostgreSQL I will use later. Or Spring Security, for example.

Do I have to use Spring Boot Profiles?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about maven/gradle dependencies. I would just comment out the ones you don't want for right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for profiles. You can read about it more eg: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement profiling for this. You can read about it more.
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1